# Binary searching a 2D array to find all the indexes of the key

Tags: c++

I am trying to binary search a 2D array which will give me the position of every key in the array, my code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<pair<int,int> > up;
vector<pair<int,int> > down;

void binsearchd(int **A,int row,int low,int high,int key)
{
    int mid=(low+high)/2;
    if(low==high&&A[row][mid]!=key)//!(A[row][mid]<=key&&A[row][mid-1]<=key&&A[row-1][mid]  <=key&&A[row+1][mid]>key&&A[row][mid+1]>key))
        return;
    if(A[row][mid]==key)//<=key&&A[row][mid-1]<=key&&A[row-1][mid]<=key&&A[row+1][mid]>key&&A[row][mid+1]>key)
    {
        down.push_back({row,mid});
        return;
    }
    if(A[row][mid]>key)
        binsearchd(A,row,low,mid,key);
    else if(A[row][mid]<key)
        binsearchd(A,row,mid+1,high,key);
    else
    {
        binsearchd(A,row,low,mid,key);
        binsearchd(A,row,mid+1,high,key);
    }
    return;
}

void searchd(int **A,int lowi,int lowj,int highi,int highj,int key)
{
    if(lowi==highi)
    {
        binsearchd(A,lowi,lowj,highj,key);
        return;
    }
    int midi=(lowi+highi)/2,midj=(lowj+highj)/2;
    if(A[midi][midj]==key)//<=key&&A[midi][midj-1]<=key&&A[midi-1][midj]<=key&&A[midi+1][midj]>key&&A[midi][midj+1]>key)
        down.push_back({midi,midj});
    if(A[midi][midj]>key)
    {
        searchd(A,lowi,lowj,midi,highj,key);
        searchd(A,midi+1,lowj,highi,midj,key);
    }
    else if(A[midi][midj]<key)
    {
        searchd(A,midi+1,lowj,highi,highj,key);
        searchd(A,lowi,midj+1,midi+1,highj,key);
    }
    else
    {
        searchd(A,lowi,lowj,midi,highj,key);
        searchd(A,midi+1,lowj,highi,highj,key);
        binsearchd(A,midi,lowj,highj,key);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int row,col;
    while(cin>>row>>col&&row){
        int **A=new int*[row];
        for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
        {
            A[i]=new int[col];
            for(int j=0;j<col;++j)
                cin>>A[i][j];
        }
        int query;
        cin>>query;
        while(query--)
        {
            int d;
            cin>>d;
            //searchu(A,1,1,row+1,col+1,u);
            searchd(A,0,0,row,col,d);
            int max=-999999999;
            //for(vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator itr=up.begin();itr!=up.end();++itr)
            //{
            for(vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator itr2=down.begin();itr2!=down.end();++itr2)
            {
                cout<<itr2->first<<" "<<itr2->second<<endl;
            }

            up.resize(0);
            down.resize(0);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<row+1;++i)
            delete A[i];
        delete A;
    }
}
```

the problem is it gives segmentation fault on array

```
4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4
```

key=4 and also in most of the time, I tried debugging found the reason of seg fault was binary searching a row 4, which is greater than the no. of row.. but I cant find out how that row can appear because my code divides the row in exactly 2 halves each time and thats how it shoudnt be able to cross the boundary.. Any hint??

Comment: Have you tried checking your arithmetic to make sure it's all sound?  You could do this with debugging or printing your index variables.

Comment: I do not think it is a problem here but you should have `mid=low+(high-low)/2` instead of `mid=(low+high)/2` to avoid overflows

Comment: There must be a wrong .. But I have tried for 2 days all night and day.. but couldnt find that..

Comment: @TamimAdDari try this instead: `searchd(A,0,0,row,col-1,d);` I think that your `col` is number of columns which are directly used as index to array. That is causing segmentation fault.

Comment: @TamimAdDari but you agree that this is a problem, right.

Comment: the row number is causing the seg fault.. I think the problem is in the case where searchd(A,midi+1,lowj,highi,highj,key); here writing midi+1 might have something to do.. but I cant figure out what else can I do...

Comment: when I search a 1D array I would pass n(no. of elements) not n-1 and it would do fine.. so here it shouldnt be a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not sure what this code is doing, an obvious oversight may be

```
searchd(A,0,0,row,col,d);
```

which should be

```
searchd(A,0,0,row-1,col-1,d);
```

This is because in the function `binsearchd` you reference the array cell `A[row][mid]`. If you pass it the raw `row` and `col` numbers it will index cells which are actually outside the array.

With this fix the code works for me, even though I'm not sure of what its output should be. This is an example output with only input 4:

```
1 1
0 1
0 1
1 1
0 1
2 1
2 1
3 1
2 1
1 1
```

Comment: The output should be
    0 0,
    0 1,
    0 2,
    0 3,
   ......
    3 2,
    3 3,
that is all the indexes where the key, here 4 was found